# Is it possible to update ModelState.IsValid manually?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to use the built-in validation features as far as possible.  I would also like to use the same model for CRUD methods.

However, as a drop down list cannot be done using the standard pattern, I have to validate it manually.  In the post back method, I would like to just validate the drop down list and add this result to ModelState so that I don't have to validate all the other parameters which are done with Data Annotation.  Is it possible to achieve this?

I may be mistaken about the drop down list, but from what I read, the Html object name for a drop down list cannot be the same as the property in the Model in order for the selected value to be set correctly.  Is it still possible to use Data Annotation with this workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use the [`addModelError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
ModelState.AddModelError(key,message)
```

when you use that, it will invalidate the ModelState so `isValid` will return false.

---

**Update**
*after seeing the comment to @Pieter's answer*

If you want to exclude an element from affecting the `isValid()` result, you can use the [`ModelState.Remove(field)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.remove%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method before calling `isValid()`.

Comment: Be careful with this if you use IValidatableObject on the model, as this validation does not run when attribute validation fails, but then again if it failed only for the property you Remove() you have an incorrectly Valid result.

Comment: Note you can leave out the key with `AddModelError(string.Empty , message)` if you want a general error not specific to a field.  This will appear in the ValidationSummary area of your page.

Comment: Just for the record, `ModelState.Remove(field)` is the answer to the OP's question, to avoid validating on fields in the model he did not want to validate on -- not using `.AddModelError()`, which just adds error messages to the model (and makes `.IsValid` return false, as posted) and has nothing to do with the scenario, IMHO.

Comment: In the interest of being explicit, the key that you pass into `ModelState.Remove` can be found in `ModelState.Keys`

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to inherit `IValidatableObject` in your model.  Implement its `Validate` method and you can leave all other validation in place and write whatever code you want in this method.  Note: you return an empty `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` to indicate there were no errors.

```
public class Class1 : IValidatableObject
{
    public int val1 { get; set; }
    public int val2 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (val1 < 0)
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationResult("val1 can't be negative", new List<string> { "val2" }));
        }
        if (val2 < 0)
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationResult("val2 can't be negative", new List<string> { "val2" }));
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

EDIT: After re-reading the question I don't think this applicable to this case, but I'm leaving the answer here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks.  This is an option for more complex situations.  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: I personally like this option better than the selected question. It keeps the logic for validating a model inside the model itself, instead of in a controller.

Comment: Thanks, knew this was possible, but couldn't remember the interface.For those that don't know, this will also add the error message 'on' the right element in your MVC pages if you use the standard scaffolding.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot manually set the ModelState.IsValid property but you can add messages to the ModelState that will ensure that the IsValid is false.

```
ModelState.AddModelError();
```

Comment: This is not what I am seeking. What I am seeking is something like the opposite: ModelState.IgnoreModelError("somekey") to ignore any validation errors of the property with somekey as key, so that ModelState.IsValid will continue to evaluate all the other parameters. The reason why I need this is because I am trying to have one model for all the CRUD methods, but the drop down list problem requires me to treat the drop down list differently in Create vs Update. The Data Annotation Required can be used in Create but not Update. For Update I will have to validate it ...

Comment: manually but I don't want its automated validation error to cause the whole model to be invalid.

Comment: Of course, I can overcome the problem by using a different model for Update. Thanks.

Comment: `ModelState.Remove(field)`, called prior to `ModelState.IsValid` was exactly what is needed to remove a field from validation.  That way any errors the ModelState has will be from fields you DO want to validate, and won't have to add those errors in with `ModelState.AddModelError()`.  I don't know why this answer got 3 upvotes.  It is correct in that you can't set `ModelState.IsValid`, and yes, you can add messages using `.AddModelError()`, but it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can achieve this (also you will use the same model for CRUD methods) :

Example MODEL

```
public class User 
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
public class Role 
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id Required.")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required.")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Example VIEW with validation on the dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.gRoles, "-- Select --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role.Id)
```

CONTROLLER: clearing the required (but not needed here) fields

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Creedit(User x)
{
    x.Role = db.RoseSet.Find(x.Role.Id);
    if (x.Role != null)
    {
        ModelState["Role.Name"].Errors.Clear();

    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // proceed
    }
    else
    {
      // return validation error
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer thanks for  ModelState["Role.Name"].Errors.Clear()

Answer (score 1):

Might be more recent methods, since this is an old post, but this might help future readers.

One can set a field to valid with this two methods:

```
ModelState.ClearValidationState("Password");
ModelState.MarkFieldValid("Password");
```

Need to use both because the second one without the first one it gives an error stating that the state is already marked.

To set a field to invalid, just use ModelState.AddModelError() method as already referred.