# ASP.NET MVC sever-side validation of select (dropdown) list selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

When handling form posts in MVC, I find myself writing some, somewhat, tedious code to ensure that the posted drop down list selections are for valid items in the list. The idea is, there's nothing preventing a post that contains a selected ID that was not originally presented in the drop down list. A user could insert their own item into the drop down list (or otherwise post whatever they want) or maybe the form has been sitting in the window for so long that the items that are now available have changed. Regardless of why it could happen, the fact is, you can't control the data that is posted. Here's some example code of how I deal with:

VM:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemID {get; set;}

    public List<Items> AvailableItems {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItemID,
                                Model.AvailableItems.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                {
                                    Value = i.ID.ToString(),
                                    Text = i.Name,
                                    Selected = (Model.SelectedItemID == i.ID)
                                }), "Select One")
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel myVM)
{
    bool isValid = true;

    try
    {
        //Reload the available items
        myVM.AvailableItems = Repository.GetAvailableItems();

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Make sure the SelectedItemID is a real item
            if(!myVM.AvailableItems.Any(i => i.ID == myVM.SelectedItemID))
            {
                isValid = false;
                myVM.SelectedItemID = null;
                ModelState.AddModelError("SelectedItemID", "Required"); //This gets interesting when the selected ID belongs to a nested VM in a collection.
            }
        }

        if(isValid)
        {
            //Finally I can process the form
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to process your submission. Please try again.");
    }

    //return an ActionResult
}
```

Setting the error in ModelState gets especially ugly if the SelectedItemID belongs to a nested view model that is inside a collection. This seems like it should be a standard type of validation but, relative to the ease of performing other validation in asp.net MVC, this is pretty ugly and tedious. Is there an easier way to take care of this?

Comment: Side note: You can remove `Selected = (Model.SelectedItemID == i.ID)`. Your binding to a property so setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored - its just unnecessary extra overhead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've found this not to be true. Without setting Selected, the dropdown list comes up blank when Model.SelectedItemID is set to a value that exists in the list.

Comment: Then you do not understand what the method does. You can set the `Selected` property to what ever your want and it WILL be ignored. Internally the `DropDownListFor()` method builds its own new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected property based on the value of the property your binding to.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I understand that with my code written as above, it renders an `<option selected="selected" value="theMatchingID">ItemX</option>` and "ItemX" is the closed dropdown's text. And that without setting `Selected`, it instead renders an `<option value="theMatchingID">ItemX</option>` and the the first option's text is displayed as the closed dropdown's text regardless of the value of `m.SelectedItemID`.

Comment: No it will not. If you omit `Selected = (Model.SelectedItemID == i.ID)` then the correct option will be still be selected (and if its not, then you have other problems with your code which you need to fix)

Comment: @stephen Just tried it several times before posting that comment. Behaves exactly as I said. You saying it doesn't, doesn't change that. So obviously there is at least one condition where it behaves that way. If you can identify what it is, that would be helpful, but arguing that it's not doing what it's doing is not. This would be interesting to look into in more detail, but for a comments section, I think we have to accept it should work like you say, but is capable of working like I say. Anyway, if this overhead pushes your server over the edge, it's time for an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at Tim Coker's response here:

[Is it possible to update ModelState.IsValid manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296361/is-it-possible-to-update-modelstate-isvalid-manually)

Basically, you want to make your viewmodel class inherit from IValidatableObject, and then put some validate logic into it. Subsequent validation calls should fail if your criteria isn't met (ie SelectedItemId not in a fresh db query)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This would help simplify adding the error to ModelState. However, in real world examples, the ViewModel containing the selected ID property may not contain the collection and/or may not have the contextual data necessary to retrieve it.